# How to publish an asp web application in IIS with setup project installer in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, setup-project

I developed an asp.net web application, I would like to generate an installer which could deploy this application in IIS automatically (or manually with published website code). I've tried to publish the code manually by myself and add them into setup project, but there always gives me an error message. I wonder if there is a way to generate an installer which could deploy my application on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps you can take.

1) Take a look at the following link which gives a plugin if you are using visual studio 2015,21017 or 2019. I think this plugin will work even with Community edition.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

2) Once the plugin is installed the following link from microsoft can guide you how you can do the setup at high level.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-create-a-web-setup-for-your-published-web-service

Hope this helps.